# How to run the javascript after page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
 <script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.appuonline.com/gadgets/mkt.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=176&amp;h=92&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23993333%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23bb5555%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23DD7777%7C0px%2C2px+solid+%23EE8888&amp;output=js"></script>
```

This script shows me the google gadget for NIFTY updates. i have called this script in my php page as

```
  <div class="sensex" align="right">
       <script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.appuonline.com/gadgets/mkt.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=176&amp;h=92&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23993333%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23bb5555%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23DD7777%7C0px%2C2px+solid+%23EE8888&amp;output=js"></script>
</div>
```

> Now, how to run this script after page load.. because it is taking time
>   to load this gadgets contents so i want to load this gadget after page
>   load.. i tried but i am not able to do that.. please can any one tell
>   me how to do it...?

Comment: There are plenty of answers to this already on the site. Did you search before you posted?

Comment: @drjimmie1976 yes i searched.. can u suggest me or give me the url for the answer that u find and which will help me too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Answer (score 0):

If you place your `<script>` to end of `body` element, then this script will be rendered when page loaded.

Other way is to write script which generate your `script` element when page is loaded and append generated `script` element to `body`.

Example of other way:

```
$(function(){
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.src = "//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.appuonline.com/gadgets/mkt.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=176&amp;h=92&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23993333%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23bb5555%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23DD7777%7C0px%2C2px+solid+%23EE8888&amp;output=js";
   $('body').append(script);
});
```

Comment: @EpsilOneR Thank you for your quick response.. i am trying to find that how to do this, that is way to write script which generate my Script

Answer (score 0):

Just use this javascript below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.appuonline.com/gadgets/mkt.xml&amp;synd=open&amp;w=176&amp;h=92&amp;title=&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23993333%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23bb5555%7C0px%2C1px+solid+%23DD7777%7C0px%2C2px+solid+%23EE8888&amp;output=js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Or you can use

```
document.onload
```

or

```
window.onload
```

Comment: Thank You but i have tried it ... it do no work because i am using script inside..

Comment: I have edit the answer please check it and tell me if it works